# Can you find $2$ sides of a quadrilateral with $2$ sides and all $4$ angles?

Tags: trigonometry, angle, quadrilateral

Not too great with math so sorry if this isnt even possible. Basically im trying to find the 2 sides that are black. I know the angles and sides that are marked in red. The 2 non right angles are not equal. Im wondering how to find the 2 sides of this quadrilateral.
[image: Quadrilateral Image]

Edit: Follow up, is it any more possible to find a, d if I was given all this:
[Quadrilateral Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNccv.png)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't, because you could easily stretch out the black sides (add some length to them) without affecting any of the angles or the red sides.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible.  Look at your diagram and imagine sliding side $c$ vertically upwards.  This would leave all the given information ($b$, $c$ and the angles) the same but would change $a$ and $d$.  So knowing $b$, $c$ and the angles is not enough information to find $a$ and $d$.

You can, however, find the difference between $a$ and $d$ if you wish:
$$d-a=c\cos A\ .$$

Comment: Thanks appreciate the answer, I do not need the difference of d and a but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not possible for both the original and the second one, as others have said, you can imagine increasing the lengths of *a* and *d* at the same rate. The angles will stay the same. This is also true in the second diagram that you made as you can now imagine them increasing in the other direction (the bottom one downwards).

When you read sliding *c* upwards, it doesn’t really help one imagine the problem with the second diagram just know that the two parallel sides can get *longer* in either direction.

This just means that you cannot find the two parallel sides of a trapezoid without one of the parallel sides.

I did draw a picture but I don’t have the rep